# SPARQL query returns null

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

Based on using SPARQL and DBPedia, I want to retrieve the information about all churches located in Paris.
If I run the code below, it returns `null`. I cannot figure out what is wrong, because there is no error message.

```
package com.tests.example;

import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;

public class JenaTestDBPedia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String queryString=
                "PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>" +
                "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>" +
                "PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>" +
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +
                "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>" +
                "PREFIX geo: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>" +
                "SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?n ?p ?d" +
                "WHERE {" +
                " ?m rdfs:label ?n." +
                " ?m skos:subject ?c." +
                " ?c skos:broader category:Churches_in_Paris." +
                " ?m p:abstract ?d." +
                " ?m geo:point ?p" +
                " }";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query); 

        try {
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
            while(results.hasNext()) {
                 QuerySolution qs = results.next();
                 RDFNode type = qs.get("label");
                 System.out.println(type.toString());
            }
        }
        finally {
           qexec.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Update:
Corrected query (though it's not working):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?n ?p ?d \n" +
                "WHERE { \n" +
                " ?m rdfs:label ?n." +
                " ?m skos:subject ?c." +
                " ?c skos:broader category:Churches_in_Paris." +
                " ?m p:abstract ?d." +
                " ?m geo:point ?p" +
                " }";
```

Comment: Where do you have the variable `label` in your query? Nowhere, exactly. It's called `n` in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to focus on the query, not the rest of the code:

- there is no `skos:subject`, you need `dct:subject`
- instead of `p:abstract`, you need `dbo:abstract`

The corrected query:

```sql
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?m ?n ?p ?d WHERE {
 ?m rdfs:label ?n.
 ?m dct:subject ?c.
 ?c skos:broader category:Churches_in_Paris.
 ?m dbo:abstract ?d.
 ?m geo:point ?p
 }
```

Some other points:

- consider filtering abstracts and labels to just those in the language that's interesting for you (probably English)
- consider making `geo:point` `OPTIONAL` as not all results have it
- consider sub-sub-categories of the parent category, not just sub-categories
- consider using variable names that are more descriptive than just a single seemingly random letter

Comment: ok, it works now. thank you. how did you figure out that there should be `dbct:subject` instead of `skos:subject`?

Comment: @HappyDuck By looking at http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Eastern_Orthodox_Churches_in_Paris (specifically the "is `dct:subject` of" row).

Comment: Ok, I see. Just curious: I checked the outputs and the query does not seem to return churches, e.g. rdfs:label - `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aomori_Museum_of_Art>`. Do you know the reason? If you do, please let me know. I will inspect it and create a new thread if I have any other doubt.

Comment: @HappyDuck That seems to be a museum in Japan, not a church in Paris.

Answer (score 0):

```
qs.get("label");
```

You didn't select a variable named label.  For the value of rdfs:label, you used the property `?n`.  You'd need to use `qs.get("n")`.

Also,  note that your string concatenation has some unintended effects like "select ... ?dWHERE { ...", and your query didn't use a variable named dWHERE.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that I should run `qs.get("?n")`  ?

Comment: No,  `qs.get("n")`, like I said in my answer.

Comment: See my updated query. I also changed to `qs.get("n")`, however still no output

Comment: @HappyDuck What do you get if you just print the results out?  Which variables around bound in the results?  E.g., try `ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);` (instead of your while loop).  We can't really guess what your query is returning without having seen you data, after all.

Comment: Ok, now it outputs `-----------------
| m | n | p | d |
=================
-----------------`. I am a newbie in Sparql and ontologies... When you say "your data", what do you mean? Probably I misunderstand some concepts of ontologies. I expected that DBPedia ontology already has all the data, i.e. classes, instances, properties, relations.

Comment: @HappyDuck Sorry, I missed the note at the beginning that you were running this against DBpedia.